# Patterns to modify value returned by a method

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, methods

I have a function that creates URLs for requests as follows:

```
public String createUrl(String path, String filename) {
        return new StringBuilder(path).append("?filename=").append(filename).toString();
        }
```

Now, what I want to do is to add another parameter to the URL called transactionId. A naive implementation would be:

```
 public String createUrl(String path, String filename,String transactionId) {
            return new StringBuilder(path).append("?filename=").append(filename).append("?transactionId=").append(transactionId).toString();
            }
```

or I can have a static method somewhere that returns a transactionID and modify the code as follows:

```
 public String createUrl(String path, String filename) {
            return new StringBuilder(path).append("?filename=").append(filename).append("?transactionId=").append(TransactionMonitor.getTransactionId()).toString();
            }
```

Both of these approaches makes me modify the preexisting code. Is there an approach that I can take to decorate the url returned by the method with new parameters. Also, it will be great if the solution is configurable.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how the second method makes you modify preexisting code. The method signature stays identical.

Comment: The signature stays identical but I am touching the internals of the function which I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: So, you would like everything in the app to stay as is, but still make it have a different behavior? Black magic is probably what you're looking for :-)

Comment: I hope I don't have to go that far. I was thinking along the lines of Spring AOP or aspectj to wrap around the method execution and append values to the original return and if that's not a possibility, I will go ahead and change the implementation to append another String. But something tells me, there might be more elegant solutions to such problems.

Comment: Configuring Spring AOP, forcing proxies and/or bytecode instrumentation to be used, making the code much harder to understand, just to avoid adding 30 characters inside a utility method doesn't look more elegant to me.

Comment: The thing is its not just 30 characters. The original code is a lot more complex with a lot of tangential concerns. What I posted was a hypothetical example of what I essentially wanted to accomplish without adding a single line of logic to an already bloated codebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create UrlBuilder class that builds url for you:

```
class UrlBuilder {

    private String path;

    private Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    public UrlBuilder path(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        return this;
    }

    public UrlBuilder parameter(String param, String value) {
        parameters.add(param, value);
        return this;
    }


    public String build() {
        String paramsString = "";

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: parameters.entrySet()) {
            if (paramsString.isEmpty()) {
                paramsString += "?";
            }
            paramsString += params.getKey() + "=" + params.getValue();
        }

        return path + paramsString;
    }

}
```

and use it in your code

`new UrlBuilder().path("http://google.com").params("q", "java").build()`

Comment: Thanks. This seems to me a step in the right direction. The Stringbuilder can be refactored out to use the utility class as you demonstrated.